# XPath3 expression which contain multiple elements in single tag

Tags: xpath

How to fetch particular element from XML using XPath3 expression which contain multiple elements in single tag, for example:

```
<REQUEST type="RETURN" success="N">
```

I want to fetch all elements which contain "N". I already tried:

```
#[xpath3('.//*:@success',payload,"STRING").contains("N")]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *multiple elements in single tag*? Elements == attributes?

Comment: I don't know what the `#[..]` stuff is - some tool that invokes an XPath 3 processor perhaps? You need to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the REQUEST elements that have the attribute success="N" using the XPath expression

```
//REQUEST[@success='N']
```

This is very basic XPath - no need for XPath 3.0 here!

You're going to have trouble getting answers to XPath questions (whether from a book, from Google, or from StackOverflow) unless you take the trouble to learn the correct names for the concepts so that you know how to formulate the question. XML does not allow tags to contain elements, so your question as phrased makes little sense.